# Subtracting a value from the current entry based on the previous column entry using LAG in MSSQL is returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, lag

I am trying to resolve the closing_stock_quantity column in a table where there are 0 values that should actually be the difference of the previous closing_stock_quantity and the quantity_sold for the current date (where the 0 value is). I.e the quantity sold for the day is subtracted from the previous quantity_closing_stock entry, to get the quantity_closing_stock for the day.

Note: There is no logic for getting the quantity_closing_stock, it is just data that has been retrieved.

With what I have tried so far, I am retrieving NULL values in place of these entries I am trying to calculate.

Here is an initial sample data:

| unit_id | timestamp | quantity | quantity_closing_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 99 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 3 | 96 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 6 | 90 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 | 5 | 95 |

I have tried to use the LAG function to resolve this, however I am receiving NULL values for those entries.

The expected output should be:

| unit_id | timestamp | quantity | quantity_closing_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 99 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 3 | 96 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 6 | 90 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 89 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 | 5 | 95 |

Here is the code I have tried:

```
WITH mycte ([timestamp],quantity_closing_stock)  AS (
    SELECT [timestamp],
        LAG(quantity_closing_stock) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
    FROM #my_table
    WHERE quantity_closing_stock = 0

)
    UPDATE #my_table
    SET quantity_closing_stock = mycte.quantity_closing_stock - quantity
    FROM #my_table AS id
     JOIN mycte ON mycte.[timestamp] = id.[timestamp]
        
SELECT * FROM  #my_table ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The LAG() on the first row will return NULL because there is no previous row because your "mycte" select only the row "WHERE quantity_closing_stock = 0",
you have to move the "WHERE quantity_closing_stock = 0" out of the calculation of the LAG().

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
/* define groups using a running conditional sum window function,
   this will group quantity_closing_stock values together til a 0 value is found
*/
WITH create_groups AS
(
  SELECT *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN quantity_closing_stock=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS grp
  FROM table_name
),
CTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
   MAX(quantity_closing_stock) OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id, grp) - 
   SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id, grp) AS val
  FROM create_groups
)
UPDATE CTE
SET quantity_closing_stock = val
WHERE quantity_closing_stock = 0;
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MI70Oaeh)

Comment: Although working with the sample provided, running on a different sample does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: Could you share the sample where the query failed.